# ruby on rails if statement on template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

```
<% @videos.each_with_index do |video, index| %>
  <% if(@video.videotype = "vimeo") %>
    <iframe width="720" height="480" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/<%=video.videourl  %>"    frameborder="0" id="player2" ></iframe>                      
  <% else %>
    <% if(@video.videotype = "youtube") %>
      <iframe width="720" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<%=video.videourl %>" frameborder="0" id="player1"></iframe>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What is wrong with this if else? all my videos display as vimeo player, but the videotype it's ok on database...

Comment: Your first immediate problem is not using the correct equality operator `==`. For a list of operators in Ruby, see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm

Comment: Instead of nesting the second `if`-statement, you can use `elsif`. See http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/ruby/ruby-if-else-if-command-syntax/

Comment: You don't need parenthesis around your checks in `if`-statements, so `if @video.videotype == "youtube"` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a few comments:

- Your first immediate problem is not using the correct equality operator `==`. For a list of operators in Ruby, see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm -- **this is what causes all your videos to show up as Vimeo**.
- Instead of nesting the second `if`-statement, you can use `elsif`. See http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/ruby/ruby-if-else-if-command-syntax/
- You don't need parenthesis around your checks in `if`-statements, so `if @video.videotype == "youtube"` is perfectly valid.
- You seem to have a floating `</div>`. It was inside the loop for videos. If you open the `<div>` before the loop, you may be producing some invalid HTML syntax.

Implementing these, would result in the following code:

```
<% @videos.each_with_index do |video, index| %>
  <% if @video.videotype == "vimeo" %>
    <iframe width="720" height="480" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/<%= video.videourl %>"    frameborder="0" id="player2" ></iframe>
  <% elsif @video.videotype == "youtube" %>
    <iframe width="720" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<%= video.videourl %>" frameborder="0" id="player1"></iframe>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I also made your spacing and indentation more coherent. This should result in more readable code.

Answer (score 1):

`=` assigns `"vimeo"` to `@video.videotype`, and since `"vimeo"` is truthy, the first `if` triggers. You want `==`, the comparison operator.

Comment: "doesn't work" is a useless status report, it provides absolutely no diagnostic power. Did you change both `=` to `==`? Did the behaviour change? How did it change? Is there an error? Did you clear your caches, both serverside and clientside?...

Comment: i change both = to == and i have the same problem

Comment: Then the problem is not here. Display the value of `@video.videotype` in the template just before the `if`; they could have been changed between the database and the template. Also, Niels Abildgaard makes excellent points on style.

Comment: the value of @video.videotype it's okay with youtube and vimeo videos... but it always take first iframe... :S

Comment: database and template have the correct value of videotype

Comment: I suggest you inspect your videotype again: make sure `@video.videotype.class.to_s` is `String`, and make sure there is no hidden spaces, or that `e` is not secretly a Cyrillic `е` or something. Also, try using Niels' code, just in case some of your markup is weird. If it still doesn't work, your Ruby is doing something impossible.

Comment: videotype varchar(255)

Comment: If you are saying that the class of `@video.videotype` displays as anything other than `String`, then comparison with a `String` can't be `true`. Try `@video.videotype.to_s == "vimeo"`. If you are stating its type in the database, that's hardly relevant.

Comment: videotype is a string. In another hand i try with @video.videotype.to_s, but doesnt solve the problem

Comment: ok, i solve the problem removed @, thanks, you helped me to improve the code :)

Comment: So, in other words, the several times that I asked you to print and report various attributes of `@video`, you were, in fact, making it up instead of actually checking? Awesome. I'm glad you solved it, but please reconsider that policy in your next question.

Answer (score 1):

You used assignment operator(=) rather than equality(==) operator.

```
<% @videos.each_with_index do |video, index| %>
   <%if(@video.videotype == "vimeo") %>
       <iframe width="720" height="480" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/<%=video.videourl  %>"    frameborder="0" id="player2" ></iframe>
   <% else %>
      <% if(@video.videotype == "youtube") %>
        <iframe width="720" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<%=video.videourl %>" frameborder="0" id="player1"></iframe>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. "=" is an assignment operator, do not use it in Ifs, it will mess the logic up here by assigning everything to "vimeo". Use "==" for comparison.
2. You can avoid such nesting conditions with elsif
3. You do not need parenthesis for if statements in views in this particular case

   ```
       <% @videos.each_with_index do |video, index| %>
       <%if @video.videotype == "vimeo" %>
         <!-- iframe for vimeo -->
       <% elsif  @video.videotype == "youtube" %>
         <!-- iframe for youtube -->
        <% end %>
       <% end %>
   ```

   Good luck, hope it works